# Redirect already logged in user with java spring-security when he tries to enter login page

Tags: java, spring-security

**Java Spring App**
_spring-security
__WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
(CUSTOM LOGIN PAGE)

***user is logged in and tries to go to the login page***

How to manage this in extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class and controller?

I've looked at several codes including custom handlers, but I can't seem to get my head around it.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
              .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/admin*").denyAll()
              .and()
          .csrf()
          .disable()
          .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/login")
          .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin")
          .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
          .and()
          .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=true");

        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }
```

**Expected**: user is redirected to the specific url
**Actual**: user gets to the page and has login form

---

*I'm aware of XML solutions and documentation but I didn't find the necessary information to understand what has to be done here. Any help would be appreciated.*

Comment: can't you replace `.antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()` with `.anonymous()` ? that would let only not logged in users go to that page

Comment: it leads to 403 when direct url is attempted by user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://bach.mystories.vn/2018/06/12/redirect-logged-in-users-when-accessing-login-page/

3 hours of search and I finally got the necessary simple info just after I posted the question so I might as well answer it myself:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

      @GetMapping("/register")
      public String register(Model model,Principal principal) {
        if(principal!=null){
          return "redirect:/";
        }
        else{
          UserRegistrationDTO userRegistrationDTO = new UserRegistrationDTO();
          model.addAttribute(userRegistrationDTO);

          return "userregistration";
        }
      }

}
```

**Adding principal parameter to the controller with redirect inside the function did the job**